# Can't set the content-type to Json in functional test

Tags: json, playframework, functional-testing

I have the following code to make a json request, but it fails:

```
Response response = POST("/b/profile/","application/json",body);
```

I also tried this one:

```
Response response = POST("/b/profile/","application/x-www-form-urlencoded",body);
```

but the response again had the content-type `text/html`. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response response = POST("/b/profile/","text/javascript",body);
```

See [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/routes#SettingthecontenttypefromHTTPheaders) for more details